# How to completely, utterly, disable spell-check on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: macos, spellcheck

With the kind of writing I do, 99 out of 100 spelling "errors" aren't errors at all. Spell correction is simply incredibly unhelpful for me. I hate the distracting red dotted underline that appears in my native Mac apps.

**What system settings can disable this?**

I've tried unchecking the available dictionaries, and changing the auto-choose-language vs. specify language ... all through the preferences panel. But even though I've unchecked US English, the system still spell checks automatically with it in apps.

Comment: Have you unchecked "Correct spelling automatically" in System Preferences > Keyboard > Text?

Comment: Yep, because spell _correction_ is disabled. I'm trying to additionally disable spell _checking_.

Comment: Have you checked out this discussion on Apple Support Communities? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2577594 It seems similar to what you have already done, but who knows…

Comment: @aaplmath Yep, I've done that, with only partial effect, and only in some apps. I'm thinking now that it's going to be an app-by-app process. E.g., TextEdit has an app-wide preferences setting to turn this off. But OmniOutliner does **not**. I'm going to ask over in their forums.

Answer (score -3):

Right-click or control-click in the field where you're working and look at the Spelling and Grammar submenu. You can also disable the various substitutions from that submenu.

Comment: I find that it disables it only for that particular run of that app. I haven't found any effect on other apps, or when restarting the app.

Comment: Are you having trouble with any other settings not "sticking" between invocations?

Comment: Hmm, not that I've noticed. I can run a disk util permissions repair and see if that helps.

Comment: It's only sticking for that one app because that's the way that setting is designed to work. It's not a system-wide toggle.

Comment: I don't expect that will, however the process outlined in [this article](https://support.apple.com/HT203538) might.

Comment: @aaplmath: While its not a system wide setting, I would expect it to remain set the next time the application is opened.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me when restarting the app either, once I go to a different "view" within the app (e.g., a new TextEdit document or a new page in Safari). Either both the OP and I are suffering from the same problem, or this is simply not how the setting is designed to work.

Comment: @aaplmathI agree. The design of this points to it not being an app-wide setting, and especially not system-wide.