# Can't disable 'Check spelling while typing' in 'Notes' in OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: macos, notes.app

This is driving me crazy.

In 'Notes', with a note text open/active, I uncheck 'Edit->Spelling and Grammar->Check spelling while typing'. Now the red underlines disappear from words believed to be spelled incorrectly, as expected. I close 'Notes', open it again. The same note text is active, but the red underlines are back. Checking the menu item above, I see that it is now checked again.

How come this setting won't stick when closing/opening 'Notes'? If I open/display another note text, then open/display the first note text, the red underlines are *not* back - it is only when 'Notes' is closed that this setting seems to be forgotten.

I have tried this:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2577594 (changing some system-wide settings, however written for a different version of OSX)
...but it doesn't help.

Possibly a similar problem (not entirely clear) on OSX Yosemite, however no solution:
[How to completely, utterly, disable spell-check on OS X Yosemite?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196376/how-to-completely-utterly-disable-spell-check-on-os-x-yosemite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**: Upgrade OS X. In El Capitan, this is simply a bug and there seems to be no workaround. This is fixed in OS X Sierra.

Comment: Well I would be delighted if that had been fixed, but I'm on 10.12.4 in freaking 2018 and this issue is still going strong. Everytime I reopen Sticky Notes, the Spell-Check is enabled.

Comment: rwenz3l, the question was about Notes, not Stickies. But anyway, it's now freaking 2022, and Stickies is fixed too.

Answer (score 2):

Quit all applications.

System Preferences > Keyboard > Text Tab. On the right side you should see "Spelling : Automatic by Language". In drop down list, choose "Set Up..." then uncheck English.

Nightmare free from those red underlines :D

Drawback: doing so will disable Spelling checking in system wide, while you may want to disable in one specific app only.

Comment: This is the solution suggested by the first link I gave;
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2577594

I have done so, that is, unchecked all languages but one, and left one I don't use checked. Didn't help.

Comment: Dude, I unchecked English Only!

Uncheck all left one didn't work for me either :)

Answer (score 1):

I am on El Capitan and wanted to turn off those red lines as well, but also keep the correction available with **<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>**, so came up with a solution that seems to work:

- Open System Preferences > Keyboard > Text.
- Click on the "Spelling" selection drop-down menu and select "Set Up".
- Disable English and all the other languages **that you use**, leave only those that you don't:
  [image: Keyboard Settings El Capitan]

This works like a charm across all of OS X.

If you, at any time, want spellchecking, then press **<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>** and select the language. It will work for the current app.

Hope it helps :)