# How to completely turn off spell check in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, keyboard, language, big-sur, spellcheck

Spelling autocorrect and checking seem to have changed in Big Sur.

I have disabled Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Check spelling while typing, I unchecked System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Correct spelling automatically, and yet I still get text underlined, for example, in Messages:

[image]

Am I missing another setting somewhere or is this a bug? In previous versions I could disable this easily.

Background: I use multiple languages and although in theory macOS can tell the difference, spell-check/autocorrect is not working too well with weird languages like Hungarian.

Comment: It looks like you're using Messages in your screenshot. I see the same behavior in Messages, but it works fine in TextEdit. Bug in Messages?

Comment: Yes you are right, I now tried a different app and it worked as expected. Seems it is specific to Messages.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be limited to the Messages app (so likely a bug) and after a few times of quitting and restarting (interestingly one restart was not enough) it too seems to finally have learned the lesson.

So my recommendation to others with similar issue:

- Set the settings as you prefer
- Don't forget about `System Prefs / Keyboard / Text / Correct spelling automatically` -  this is either new in Big Sur (not sure) or it was toggled on again after update
- Patiently restart your apps a few times (or perhaps a full system restart) and this should resolve the issue

Comment: The system prefs thing worked for me. Autocorrect on your phone is annoying enough but on a Mac, with a keyboard, where you type much more accurately, is infinitely annoying. I couldn't type "Gronk"!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to **globally turn it off**, please check my answer to this same question, on this already older/existent topic:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411622/341083